# Getting SQLException in Phoenix JDBC client

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-phoenix

I am writing a JDBC Client to access Phoenix. I tried the following basic code for to Create, load and retrieve data from a Table. I tried comparing versions and looking for Issues, but I couldn't get the exact reason for this Exception. Is this a bug, or do you have an explanation?

**Version Info-** Hbase: 0.98.0.2.1.5.0 ; Phoenix: phoenix-4.0

**Code:**

```
public class PheonixTest {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    String phoenixDriver = "org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver";
    try {

        Class.forName(phoenixDriver);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }

    try {

        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rset = null;
        System.out.println("Connecting ... >");
        Connection con = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:phoenix:<zookeeper>");

        System.out.println("In Connection Statement -- >");

        stmt = con.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS us_population_java2 (  state CHAR(2) NOT NULL,  city VARCHAR NOT NULL,  population BIGINT  CONSTRAINT my_pk PRIMARY KEY (state, city));");
        stmt.executeUpdate("upsert into us_population_java values ('NY','New York',8143197)");
        stmt.executeUpdate("upsert into us_population_java values ('CA','Los Angeles',3844829)");
        stmt.executeUpdate("upsert into us_population_java values ('NY','New York',8143197)");
        stmt.executeUpdate("upsert into us_population_java values ('CA','Los Angeles',3844829)");
        System.out.println("After Execute Update Statement -- >");
        con.commit();

        PreparedStatement statement = con
                .prepareStatement("select * from us_population_java");

        rset = statement.executeQuery();

        while (rset.next()) {
            System.out.println("In Print Statement -- >");
            System.out.println(rset.getString("state"));
        }
        statement.close();
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

**Exception:**

```
java.sql.SQLException: ERROR 2007 (INT09): Outdated jars. The following servers require an updated phoenix.jar to be put in the classpath of HBase: region=SYSTEM.CATALOG
    at org.apache.phoenix.exception.SQLExceptionCode$Factory$1.newException(SQLExceptionCode.java:386)
    at org.apache.phoenix.exception.SQLExceptionInfo.buildException(SQLExceptionInfo.java:145)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.checkClientServerCompatibility(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:994)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.ensureTableCreated(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:867)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.createTable(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1213)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.DelegateConnectionQueryServices.createTable(DelegateConnectionQueryServices.java:112)
    at org.apache.phoenix.schema.MetaDataClient.createTableInternal(MetaDataClient.java:1902)
    at org.apache.phoenix.schema.MetaDataClient.createTable(MetaDataClient.java:744)
    at org.apache.phoenix.compile.CreateTableCompiler$2.execute(CreateTableCompiler.java:186)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$2.call(PhoenixStatement.java:300)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$2.call(PhoenixStatement.java:292)
    at org.apache.phoenix.call.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:53)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeMutation(PhoenixStatement.java:290)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeUpdate(PhoenixStatement.java:1180)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$12.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1891)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$12.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1860)
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixContextExecutor.call(PhoenixContextExecutor.java:77)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.init(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1860)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.getConnectionQueryServices(PhoenixDriver.java:162)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.connect(PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.java:131)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.connect(PhoenixDriver.java:133)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.go.check.PheonixTest.main(PheonixTest.java:29)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your versions are incompatible: http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Using+Apache+Phoenix+on+HBase.

**In prereqs**

> Apache Phoenix version 4.0 requires HBase 0.98.1 or later.

You could try downgrading your Phoenix or upgrading your Hbase.

Comment: Cogan :Thanks for your reply ! let me try that.